# JDeveloper 11g Not Opening

Tags: ide, jdeveloper, jdeveloper-11g

I am trying to open up jdeveloper 11g and it is doing nothing. I am getting the following error when I run jdev.exe

```
IDE boot startup failed.
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: oracle/classloader/SharedCodeSourceURL
        at oracle.ide.boot.IdeLauncher.initURLStreamHandlerFactory(IdeLauncher.j
ava:146)
        at oracle.ide.boot.IdeLauncher.launchImpl(IdeLauncher.java:87)
        at oracle.ide.boot.IdeLauncher.launch(IdeLauncher.java:65)
        at oracle.ide.boot.IdeLauncher.main(IdeLauncher.java:54)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at oracle.ide.boot.Launcher.invokeMain(Launcher.java:713)
        at oracle.ide.boot.Launcher.launchImpl(Launcher.java:115)
        at oracle.ide.boot.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:68)
        at oracle.ide.boot.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:57)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.classloader.SharedCodeSource
URL
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:305)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:246)
```

I attempted to install oracle servicce bus and oracle database express edition, is it possible that some file was overwritten?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next thing to do after deleting the system11.1.x.x.x.x folder is to remove or uninstall the whole JDev and after that install it again. Then all files which might be overwritten by the other installations should be back in their original version.

You should install JDev into a path without spaces in.

Timo

Answer (score 4):

Try removing JDeveloper's system directory 
Should be under C:\Users\yourUser\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper
and then restarting JDeveloper

Looks like it is trying to open a file that it has no access to over the network.

Comment: I just did this and it and I am still getting this, any more ideas?

Comment: Be careful! Doing this will delete all your previous defined settings.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I need update JDevepoper to newest. It will fix this issue

[image]

Another option is setting proxy for Jdeveloper. Choose Window/Preference, search proxy, choose Proxy Setting. Enter proxy information.

[image]